# How are the expressions equal?

Tags: inequality

In a paper i recently read , the author claims that:

(1) ${e^{ - a{{(r + (1/2){\sigma ^2})}^2}\tau /(2{\sigma ^2})}}$ = (2) ${e^{ - {1 \over 4}{{(\gamma  + 1)}^2}a\tau }}$

For (2) the following are true

$\gamma  = {{2r} \over {{\sigma ^2}}}$

$\tau  = \tau *{{{\sigma ^2}} \over 2}$

I think he has made an error because i cannot see the two expressions being equal? Can someone spot a possible typo?

Comment: Your second requires that $\sigma = \sqrt 2$ or $\tau=0$ Is that what you meant to say?  Certainly from the first equality we cannot conclude the last two without other information.

Comment: what i meant to say is that in expression (2) , gamma is equal to ${{2r} \over {{\sigma ^2}}}$ and tau is equal to $\tau *{{{\sigma ^2}} \over 2}$. This is only the case in the second expression

Comment: As gamma is used in the second and not the first, this can be a definition of gamma that helps make the two expressions equal.  tau is used on both sides so maybe the ones on the right should have a prime or something.  Then the two expressions would be equal because he defined new variables.  One would do this if the new form were easier for some upcoming manipulation.

Comment: well gamma is ${{2r} \over {{\sigma ^2}}}$ so thats already defined, when it comes to tau, yes you are right he first defines tau as $\tilde \tau  = \tau *{{{\sigma ^2}} \over 2}$ but then drops the tilda for notational simplicity. Still i dont see how the two expressions are equal ?

Answer (score 0):

$$(r+(1/2)\sigma^2)^2=(\frac {2r}{\sigma^2}+1)^2\frac {\sigma^4}4=(\gamma+1)^2\frac {\sigma^4}4$$
The $\frac 14$ remains, two of the powers of $\sigma$ cancel the two that were there and two are absorbed into the redefinition of $\tau$  The $2$ that was there is also absorbed into the redefinition of $\tau$

Comment: hm....so the equality holds?

Comment: Yes, but it is just a consequence of the definitions of $\gamma$ and $\tilde \tau$.  They were defined to make this work.

Comment: why is there no a ?

Comment: It is a common factor on both sides, so nothing needs to happen to it.